# Filtering on date using conditional in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Trying to simply filter on year, or date. See below where *data2* is a tibble and `Contract Date` is a type date field.

```
 recent <- data2 %>%
    filter(data2,`Contract Date` >("01-01-2016"))
```

*Error in FUN(left, right) : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types*

Update:

See head of data2 below:

```
A tibble: 6 x 52
  CONTACTID Status `Contract Date` `Country of Ori~ `CES Submitted` `Embassy Date` `Hire Date` Agent `ATT Received` `CES Issued Dat~ `CES Ready Revi~ `CES RFR 8 week~ `I-140 Sent` `I-140 Recd.` `I-140 Result D~ `I-140 Status` `CES Status` `Choice of Agen~ Client `Contact Owner`
  <chr>     <chr>  <date>          <chr>            <chr>           <chr>          <chr>       <chr> <chr>          <chr>            <chr>            <lgl>            <chr>        <chr>         <chr>            <chr>          <chr>        <chr>            <chr>  <chr>          
1 zcrm_257~ Finis~ NA              Philippines      NA              NA             6/22/2015   NA    NA             NA               NA               FALSE            NA           NA            NA               NA             NA           NA               Oakbe~ Tyler Richards 
2 zcrm_257~ Finis~ 2015-12-15      England          NA              12/5/2016      2/20/2017   Adev~ NA             NA               NA               FALSE            4/14/2016    6/29/2011     4/25/2016        Approved       NA           5/25/2016        Oakbe~ Eddie Money    
3 zcrm_257~ Finis~ 2015-11-09      Philippines      NA              NA             11/17/2015  Ulti~ NA             NA               NA               FALSE            NA           NA            NA               NA             NA           NA               Oakbe~ Eddie Money    
4 zcrm_257~ Finis~ 2016-03-03      Philippines      NA              NA             3/21/2016   NA    NA             NA               NA               FALSE            NA           NA            NA               NA             NA           NA               Oakbe~ Eddie Money    
5 zcrm_257~ Finis~ 2006-08-15      Philippines      NA              3/21/2016      6/27/2016   IQ    NA             NA               NA               FALSE            3/1/2007     3/2/2007      3/8/2007         Approved       NA           7/10/2007        Oakbe~ alyssa Coleman 
6 zcrm_257~ Relea~ 2016-07-20      Philippines      NA              NA             9/12/2016   Ulti~ NA             NA               NA               FALSE            NA           NA            NA               NA             NA           NA               Oakbe~ Eddie Money    
# ... with 32 more variables: `DS260 Completed` <chr>, Elite <lgl>, `Embassy Status` <chr>, `Fee Bill Received` <chr>, `Fee Bill Returned` <chr>, `Hospital Country` <chr>, `Hospital Size` <dbl>, `IELTS Test Date` <chr>, `Initial Ready for Review` <chr>, `Instruction Pkt.
```

Comment: It seems that `filter()` does not support the class `Date`.  Read the documentation better or use another approach.

Comment: Compare with `as.Date("2016-01-01")` if your column is a date

Comment: Thanks @Clemsang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because you're trying to compare if character 1 is greater than character 2. You must first coerce `Contract Date` *and*  the text to filter out to `date`.

For example:

```
recent <- data2 %>% 
  mutate(`Contract Date` = lubridate::ymd(`Contract Date`)) %>%
  filter(`Contract Date` > as.Date("2016-01-01"))
```

Comment: thank you very much for your response. I posted the following:

recent <- data2 %>% 
  mutate(`Contract Date` = lubridate::dmy(`Contract Date`)) %>%
  filter(data2, `Contract Date` > as.POSIXct("2016-01-01")) ---- and received --------- Error in FUN(left, right) : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
In addition: Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

Comment: `dmy()` is a function from the `Lubridate` package to coerce characters in the format of "dd-mm-yyyy" to `Date`. I don't know what class or format your ``Contract Date`` column is in. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: So confused as it seems like it should work and be straight forward; posted updated answer in (save I changed date2 to data 2) and it kicks this--- Error in FUN(left, right) : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types --- maybe contefranz is right?

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks for putting me on.

Comment: Seems I've been sloppy. You need to leave the first argument (data) of `filter` out since it's already been passed by the pipe `%>%`.